# Complex Analysis boundedness and limits

Tags: complex-analysis

True or false. If $f: \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is bounded, then $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)$ exists.

R If f is bounded means that there is some M∈R such that ∀z ∈C holds that |f(z)|≤M.

**My Answer**

Would $\frac{z}{|z|+1}$ be an example of such a function? Bounded above by 1 and below by -1.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to produce any counterexample?

Comment: What a strange problem ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without additional assumptions, this doesn't hold: Consider

$f(z) = \begin{cases} 1\text{, if }\Re(z) \ge 0 \\ 0 \text{, if } \Re(z) < 0 \end{cases}$

Answer (score 3):

False. Take the function that is $1$ on the real axis and $0$ elsewhere.