# complex analysis -examples of complex functions that are bounded and the limits

Tags: complex-analysis

What are some examples of complex functions that are bounded and the limits does not exists as $z\to 0$?

Comment: How about $\frac{\bar{z}}{z}$?

Comment: If you want a meromorphic function, there are only three possibilities. Having no limit as $z \rightarrow 0$ narrows this down to only one of the three, so you need to come up a function that exhibits that "really bad" behavior and use a Moebius transformation to move the bad point to 0.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400779/complex-analysis-boundedness-and-limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(z)=\frac{z}{|z|}$.

Also, let $g(z)$ be any analytic function with $g(0)\neq 0$ and let

$$h(z)=\frac{z}{|z|}g(z) \,.$$

Comment: How about $\frac{\bar{z}}{z}$?

Comment: @Avinesh That is just $\overline{f^2}$ ;) There are many many other such functions....

Answer (score 0):

$$f(z)={\Big\{}\begin{array}[ll]{ll}0 & \Re z\in\mathbb{Q}\\ 1& \Re z\in\mathbb{Q}\end{array}$$